# c# file move (file is already used by another process)

Tags: c#

I am moving files from one folder to another. If I try to move the entire folder to the folder within that particular folder I cannot do that. But if I move it outside it works fine. How can I move my folder to the folder within that folder?

**this gives error**

```
  if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(PhysicalPath))
 {
      string sourcePath = "c:\\copypath\\";
      string targetPath = "c:\\copypath\\abc\\";
      System.IO.Directory.Move(sourcePath, targetPath);
 }
```

**this works fine**

```
 if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(PhysicalPath))
 {
      string sourcePath = "c:\\copypath\\";
      string targetPath = "c:\\abc\\";
      System.IO.Directory.Move(sourcePath, targetPath);
 }
```

Comment: So you want a folder in your folder, so you can folder while you folder?

Comment: "this gives error": what kind of error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to  "c:\copypath\" into "c:\copypath\abc\" won't work because it doesn't make sense.

If you move the copypath folder then it won't exist anymore, so how will the target folder (which is a subfolder) of it exist?

You could move all of the child files of "c:\copypath\" into "c:\copypath\abc\" instead, which wouldn't cause a problem (again assuming you don't try to copy abc into itself).

Comment: +1 for explaining the non-sense of the OP's approach. The entire point of a "move" is that the original directory path STOPS existing after the move. Perhaps you can update your answer to define what a "move" actually is. Also, instead of doubling the space used during this operation, the OP should create the subdirectory and move the files and subfolders to the new subfolder.

Answer (score 2):

It throws away the error, because you are trying to move a directory in its own subdirectory. This would give an error in windows as well...

You can do this as an alternate, if you are trying to copy rather than move...

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(PhysicalPath))
{
      string sourcePath = "c:\\copypath\\";
      string targetPath = "c:\\copypath\\abc\\";
      System.IO.Directory.Copy(sourcePath, targetPath);
}
```

Comment: Kinda like a rabbit trying to pull itself out of a hat by its ears

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to move all the files inside the folder, rather than the folder itself?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the sourcepath will be in use (copying of files) and since the destination path is a subfolder of source path it might give you "Currently used by another process error".